# How to add borders to components when using GroupLayout?

Tags: java, swing, border, grouplayout

For example, I have two radio buttons and I want a border around them so that the UI looks clearer? Tried searching but didn't find anything useful. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below would create a border around your radio buttons. You can create different type of borders, check the [BorderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html) API for a description about the different borders

```
JRadioButton yesButton   = new JRadioButton("Yes", true);
JRadioButton noButton    = new JRadioButton("No", false);

ButtonGroup bgroup = new ButtonGroup();
bgroup.add(yesButton);
bgroup.add(noButton);

JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
radioPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
radioPanel.add(yesButton);
radioPanel.add(noButton);

radioPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
           BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "BorderTitle"));
```

Comment: I was hoping there was another way, not using panels, oh well, thanks.

Comment: This is the approach recommended in the `JComponent` API,

Answer (score 3):

Create a panel, put those radio buttons in that panel.. and create a border around the panel

[How to use borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)